# Is there any possibility to control model callback for only one controller method call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i need to use model callback when only selected action in controller

```
class TestController
 def end_exam(); end
 def resume_exam(); end
 def continue_exam(); end
 def review_exam(); end
end

class Test //Model
 after_find :include_load_question_module // only for end_exam, resume, continue
end // not for review_exam
```

is there any possibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, in Test model (app/models/test.rb):

```
skip_callback(:find, :after, :review_exam)
```

Comment: Not true - models don't know anything about controller actions

Answer (score 1):

You can get detailed information in below link

http://www.gsubbarao.com/2012/11/ruby-on-rails-3x-skip-callback-and.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this magically: the model has no concept of who is calling it, so it can't change its behaviour based on the current controller action.

You'd be better off having a controller `before_filter` that calls `include_load_question_module` on the relevant instances.